# How does an int variable casted to char* print a string?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how a line of this code is working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 6513249

int main()
{
        int a = NUM;
        char * pt = (char *) &a;
        printf("a is: %d\n", a);

        //Line I don't understand (I think)
        printf("string is: %s\n", pt)

        return 0;
}
```

### Expected and actual output:

> a is: 6513249
> string is: abc

To be clear, this program is supposed to print this string, I just don't really understand fully how it is doing it.

My current understanding is that when you cast an address of a variable with integer type to a pointer with char pointer type, the pointer points to only the first memory address that the int variable was stored in.

What I don't understand is how the pointer, which as I understand will pass the first memory address of **a**, is being converted to to the string "abc". Is there a flaw in my understandings of casting and printing pointers?

Comment: This code has implementation-dependent behavior. It's depending on the fact that the binary representation of that number happens to be the same as the string `abc`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, what I'm confused about is how exactly that's getting converted and printed in the last print statement. Is it getting a binary value then converting that to a string?

Comment: @Barmar nvm, your answer clarified, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number `6513249` has the hex value `00636261`. On a little-endian architecture, the bytes are stored least-significant first, so this is stored in memory as

```
61 62 63 00
```

`61` is the ASCII code for `a`, `62` is the ASCII code for `b`, and `63` is the ASCII code for `c`. So this is the same memory contents as the string `"abc"` (`00` is the null terminator). So if we treat the address of `a` as the beginning of a string (by casting `&a` to `char*`) and print it, we get `abc`.

This is totally unportable.

Comment: Ah ok I see, that explains it. So does that mean when an int is declared it is stored based on its hex value?

Comment: It's stored in binary. Hex is just a way of picturing the value that happens to make the bytes easy to see. Every 2 hex digits is 1 byte.

Comment: That makes much more sense, thank you for the answer and clarification!